# How can I parametize a curve of intersection of two surfaces?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

To find out **directional derivative**  $f(x.y.z)=x^2+y^2−z^2$ at $(3,4,5)$ along the curve of

intersection of the two surfaces $2x^2+2y^2−z^2=25$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$

I am trying to parametrize above two surfaces $r(t)$ and find out vector.

But, I am not sure what value of $t$ should be and is it right way to find out directional

derivative.

If there is any other way, please explain .

Answer (score 1):

How to do it:

In this simple example it is actually possible to give an explicit parametrization of the curve of intersection $\gamma$ in terms of elementary functions. But in general you cannot count on such luck. Fortunately it is possible to compute this directional derivative without computing $\gamma$.

We are given two surfaces
$$S_1:\quad  g(x,y,z)=0,\qquad S_2:\quad h(x,y,z)=0$$
that intersect transversally at a given point $P$. This means that $\nabla g(P)$ and $\nabla h(P)$ are linearly independent. The cross product $$n:=\nabla g(P)\times \nabla h(P)\ne0$$ is orthogonal to both gradients; therefore it belongs to both tangent planes and is in fact a tangent vector of the curve $\gamma=S_1\cap S_2$ at $P$, albeit not normalized.

In addition we are given a real-valued function $f$ defined in the neighborhood of $P$, and we are told to compute the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $n$. Since $\gamma$ has no a priori sense of direction this directional derivative is only defined up to sign, and is given by
$$\pm{1\over |n|}\>\nabla f(P)\cdot n\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

If you plug $z^2=x^2+y^2$ into $2x^2+2y^2-z^2=25$, you will get the intersection $x^2+y^2=25, z=5$, which is a circle. The parametric equation is then $(5\cos{t},5\sin{t},5), t\in[0,2\pi]$. And yes, you can use that to find directional derivative.

Comment: What I am confused is that  I dont still get what the value of t should be. Could you explain more about it ?

Comment: To get the unit vector, t should be value of ...what?

Comment: You don't need the unit vector. In this case, you are lucky that the value $\nabla f(r(t))\cdot r'(t)$ is just a constant.

Comment: But, in order to find out directional derivative, don't you have to multiply gradient of f by unit vector?

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant. Find $r'(t)$ first, then find its norm. You will see you don't need the value of $t$ to find the unit vector. If you do need it, then remember the point (3,4,5). You can assume that $\cos{t}=3/5$ and $\sin{t}=4/5$.